# Searching for the rest of a word in a list python

Tags: python, regex, list, search

The user will type in an entry field. After each letter they type it will search a list for the rest of the word. For instance, if the user typed `Ar` and the `list = ["Arial","Cat","Pie","Terminal"]`, it would replace what they where typing with `Arial` because the first couple of letters match. 
Now keep in mind I am relatively new to python so I don't get regex. I can handle the word change and so forth. I just need help with searching the list.

Here is the code:

```
fonts = ["Arial","Calibri","Cambria","Cambria Math","Candara","Comic Sans MS","Consolas","Constantia","Corbel","Courier","Courier New","Fixedsys","Franklin Gothic","Gabriola","Georgia","Impact","Lucida Console","Lucida Sans Unicode","Modern","MS Sans Serif","MS Serif","Palatino Linotype","Roman","Segoe Print","Segoe Script","Segoe UI","Segoe UI Symbol","Small Fonts","Small Fonts","System","Tahoma","Terminal","Times New Roman","Trebuchet MS","Verdana"]

def findfontname(event):
       #Search list:
       for item in fonts:
           if item == findfont.get(0,END):
               print("Found")

findfont.bind("<Key>", findfontname)
```

Comment: This problem have nothing to do with Tkinter - finding text on list is normal Python problem.

Comment: @furas Yeah sorry Mixed it in there because it involved a gui entry field.

Comment: Use `in` to check if some text is inside other text.

Comment: or `startswith()` = `starts with`

Comment: what behavior do you want if the user enters 'ca'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how the rest of your code looks like, but hopefully I can give you a helpful demo. As far as I understand your question, you want to check whether a string from your list of fonts starts with a given substring.

```
>>> fonts = ["Arial","Calibri","Cambria","Cambria Math"]
>>> sub = 'xYz' # there should be no match for this
>>> sub = sub.lower() # convert to lowercase
>>> [x for x in fonts if x.lower().startswith(sub)]
[]
```

So this first example returns an empty list, which evaluates to `False` in a boolean context.

```
>>> sub = 'Ar'
>>> sub = sub.lower()
>>> [x for x in fonts if x.lower().startswith(sub)]
['Arial']
```

This returns one result, so you should be able to display 'Arial' now. Problems arise when the user enters something which starts with C.

```
>>> sub = 'cA'
>>> sub = sub.lower()
>>> [x for x in fonts if x.lower().startswith(sub)]
['Calibri', 'Cambria', 'Cambria Math']
```

As you can see, there are three possible matches. It's your design decision now whether to show all matches, or show nothing until there is only one match. If you want the latter option, you could issue something like this:

```
matches = [x for x in fonts if x.lower().startswith(sub)]
if len(matches) == 1: # exactly one match
    match = matches[0]
    # code to display the match
```

Final note: If your list of fonts grows large, consider making it a `set`.

Comment: this works perfect I tryed using in but it did not work correctly thanks!

Comment: @cdw100100 using `in` fails because, for example, when the user starts his input with 'm', then `'m' in 'Cambria'`will return `True`.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly happening

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to check if some text is inside other text in any place

```
fonts = ["Arial","Calibri","Cambria","Cambria Math","Candara","Comic Sans MS","Consolas","Constantia","Corbel","Courier","Courier New","Fixedsys","Franklin Gothic","Gabriola","Georgia","Impact","Lucida Console","Lucida Sans Unicode","Modern","MS Sans Serif","MS Serif","Palatino Linotype","Roman","Segoe Print","Segoe Script","Segoe UI","Segoe UI Symbol","Small Fonts","Small Fonts","System","Tahoma","Terminal","Times New Roman","Trebuchet MS","Verdana"]

text = findfont.get(0,END):
text = text.lower()

for item in fonts:
    if text in item.lower():
       print("Found")
```

You can use `startswith()` if you search text starting with other text

```
text = findfont.get(0,END):
text = text.lower()

for item in fonts:
    if item.lower().startswith(text):
       print("Found")
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to implement some form of autocompletion functionality, so `in` won't be helpful. I could be wrong of course, but that's how I understood the question.

Comment: @furas Thanks it works great also I got a error with the .get(0,END) saying to many arguments so i removed the (0,END) and now it works great!

Comment: If `findfont` is `StringVar` then it use different function then `Text` widget.

Comment: @furas unfortunately in did not work correctly but I figured it out thanks for the help though!